# onPress not getting called , throwing an error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have following code where onPress i m expecting to call a function.

```js
class BarButton extends Component {
    render() {
        const {imageUri,onPress} = this.props;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}
                              onPress={() => onPress()}
            >
                <Image source={imageUri} style = {styles.buttonStyle}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

BarButton.propTypes = {
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    imageUri:PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default class ShopScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Shop',
        headerRight: <BarButton imageUri={require('./images/filter.png')} onPress={ this.onPressButton}/>,
        headerTintColor:'black'
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true}
        this.onPressButton = this.onPressButton.bind(this);
    }
    onPressButton()
    {
        
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Filter');
    }
```

So I want to call the function onPressButton and navigate to next screen , in this I get error

[image]

Comment: so you get this error when the component mounts? or when you invoke onPressButton?

Comment: I get this on onPress

Comment: I'm going to assume that your `this` in your `static` object cannot not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically as a newbie i failed to understand that navigationOptions is a static var so can't reference anything using "this", following thread proposes many solutions here is the original link and out of all the on worked for me is as follows, posting it here for ease (with due credit to original author https://github.com/jacse)

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/145

```js
class MyScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
        return {
            headerRight: <Button title="Save" onPress={() => params.handleSave()} />
        };
    };

    _saveDetails = () => {
        console.log('clicked save');
        console.log('clicked save ' + this.state.xxxxxx);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this._saveDetails });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `navigation` object that `navigationOptions` receive when you use a function instead of an object.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {        
    return {
        title: 'Shop',
        headerRight: (
           <BarButton
              imageUri={require('./images/filter.png')}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Filter')}
           />
        ),
        headerTintColor:'black'
    };
};
```

Comment: Did you get any error? If `ShopScreen` is a "real" Screen, `navigation` should be defined and you should be able to use `navigation.navigate()`